# How to accommodate huge URL in Internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, url, iframe, browser

I was working with google maps.
And I was sending data(latitude & longitude along with their addresses) to iframe through URL. The whole size of the url can be 20-30K long characters in my case.

Now it's working fine in Chrome as it supports 64K characters. 
But It's creating problem for internet explorer as it supports only 2083 characters.

Do you have any idea how to overcome this problem?

Can we compress the URL string while sending & then decompress it in the iframe?

or

Is there any other feasible way to pass data to iframe?

Comment: Why don't you programmatically shorten the url ? You could use google's API https://goo.gl/

Comment: Can you do a POST to the iframe by specifying `target="my-iframe-name"`?

Comment: I'm sending the data from server to client. I guess post works from client to server